# How to update an Android app using an APK without user interaction at all?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a robot Android app where I've added a class that updates the app automatically.
We get the new APK version from a local server where the robot is located.

However, when there is a new APK and after downloading it to the storage of the device and when executing the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
final Context context = this.context.get();
Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", apkFile);
intent.setData(apkUri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

the window below asks the user's action to either **CANCEL** or **INSTALL**.

Is there any way to execute the **INSTALL** button without users needing to press it?

[image]

Comment: What type of Android device are you updating the app on (custom hardware, consumer phone, etc.)?

Comment: @MorrisonChang
Thank you for asking. It is a custom Android tablet `Android 9 Level 28` for a delivery serving robot!

Comment: You should check with the manufacturer of the Android tablet to see if there is a managed device mode / device policy controller available or other API. Only at that system level can you have silent app install. See: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices#managed_devices